# VS Code can't step into linked library project

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

VS Code 1.48, Ubundu 18.04, cmake 3.10, gdb 8.1-ubuntu3.2, gcc 7.5.0.

VSC newb, ubuntu newb, unix experienced, cmake experienced, gdb newb, c++ grizzled vet.  I'm mostly a windows guy, though I've dabbled with various flavors of Unix since college back in the early 90s.  *wheeze*

I have two project directories loaded into my VSC workspace... both written in C++ with a dash of python hither and yon.  The first, we'll call it Orc, works great.  All it's tests pass, it's cmake-defined install ran just fine.  Life is good.

The second project, we'll call Elf, builds fine, and works fine until it needs to depend on Orc, at which point I get a seg fault.  Another call to that same library succeeded (the version check:trivial, no parameters), though I cannot step into that either.  When it comes time to tell Orc to do some actual work: boom.  I also haven't noticed any core dumps lying about to be interrogated.

(side question: where does VSC stash its core dumps?)

I made sure both projects are debug builds.  They're both using the same version of Boost.  I've succeeded in running all our unit tests in both Orc and Elf on windows.

What do I need to do to be able to step into Orc so I can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Also, when I "f12" on the Orca function in question, it takes me to the installed version of the file... hmm... do I need to install the debug output files as well?  I'm not eve sure what their extension would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my `CMakeLists.txt` and it seems to be happy.  There's probably a better way to do it though.

```
if (UNIX)
  add_definition(-ggdb)
endif()
```

Down side:  Always adds -ggdb to Linux builds, including Release... not just the debug variants.  Problems in with non-gdb debuggers.

I'm guessing there's a better way to specify a debug-only flag like this, but I'm not sure what that might be.  I'm getting familiar with CMake, but I'm no expert.